# Modifying get accessor c#

Tags: c#, get, set, accessor

Fairly new to using the accessors without just using shorthand. I'm trying to change a property based on another property, without it being able to be set somewhere else. Essentially I want to have it like so;

```
public int Salary { get; set; }
public int Tax
{
    get
    {
        if (Salary > 2000)
        {
            return Tax = 20;
        }
        else if (Salary > 1500)
        {
            return Tax = 10;
        }
        else
        {
            return Tax = 5;
        }
    }
}
```

So that it's not possible for to be able to change the Tax property itself, however I get an error saying "Property Customer.Tax cannot be assigned to as it is readonly" And i understand the issue, but i don't get how to solve it.

Comment: So you understand that you can't ever assign anything to `Tax`, but you don't understand how to solve an error telling you that you're trying to assign a value to `Tax`?  If you know you can't do it, and you're doing it, you know you need to not do it...

Answer (score 4):

If `Tax` is readonly, then it is very similar to a "classical" method (like a `GetTax()`):

```
public int Tax
{
    get
    {
        if (Salary > 2000)
        {
            return 20;
        }
        else if (Salary > 1500)
        {
            return 10;
        }
        else
        {
            return 5;
        }
    }
}
```

There is no assignment... Every time you query `Tax`, its value is calculated.

In the end a property is only primarily a trick for "keeping together" two methods, a getter and a setter... Normally these two methods "act" on a backing field (the field where the value of the property is saved). Clearly in your case you don't have a backing field and don't have a setter. You only have a getter that is always recalculated. Some languages (like Java) don't have this "trick", and use directly properties like `getFoo()` and `setFoo()` and live perfectly well.

Answer (score 0):

You can also solve this issue, by determining the taxes when setting the Salary property, and using a private setter for the Tax property.
This means you won't have to re-calculate the taxes every time you call them (granted, it won't make a big deal with these small numbers, but depending on the project, this will come in useful)

```
public class PayCheck {

    private double _salary = -1;

    public double Salary {
        get => _salary;
        set {
            _salary = value;
            if (value > 2000)
                Tax = 20;
            else if (value > 1500)
                Tax = 10;
            else
                Tax = 5;
        }
    }

    public double Tax { get; private set; }

}
```